# How can I retrieve a String array from JSONObject?

Tags: java

My `JSONArray` contains various `JSONObject`s which look like this:

```
{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["OPS","BHU"],"y":0}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":1}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":2}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":3}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":4}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":5}

{"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":6}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":0}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":1}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":2}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["DDF","THG"],"y":3}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":4}

{"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":5}

{"nearby":1,"x":1,"name":["ABC","DEF","XYZ"],"y":6}
```

I want to retrieve values corresponding to `name` key in `JSONObject` and from an array like this:

```java
JSONObject jo= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String nearby= jo.getString("nearby");
String xString= jo.getString("x");
int x=Integer.parseInt(xString);
String yString= jo.getString("y");
int y=Integer.parseInt(yString);
String[][] name=new String[7][7];
name[x][y]= ????????
```

Such that the output be like:

```java
name[0][0]=["OPS","BHU"]
name[0][1]=["None"]
name[0][2]=["None"]
name[0][3]=["None"]
name[0][4]=["None"]
name[0][5]=["None"]
name[0][6]=["None"]
name[1][0]=["None"]
name[1][1]=["None"]
name[1][2]=["None"]
name[1][3]=["DDF","THG"]
name[1][4]=["None"]
name[1][5]=["None"]
name[1][6]=["ABC","DEF","XYZ"]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - make sure you reduce it to a *minimal* but complete example, well-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```js
var arr = [
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["OPS","BHU"],"y":0},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":1},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":2},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":3},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":4},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":5},
    {"nearby":0,"x":0,"name":["None"],"y":6},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":0},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":1},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":2},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["DDF","THG"],"y":3},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":4},
    {"nearby":0,"x":1,"name":["None"],"y":5},
    {"nearby":1,"x":1,"name":["ABC","DEF","XYZ"],"y":6},
  ]

  var resultArr = [[],[]];

  $.each(arr, function (key, item) {
    resultArr[item.x][item.y]=item.name;
  });

    console.log(resultArr[0][0])
    console.log(resultArr[0][1])
    console.log(resultArr[0][5])
    console.log(resultArr[1][4])
    console.log(resultArr[1][6])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```